# Hadoop SequenceFile: process key/value only up to a certain size?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a Sequence File that contains ~ 12,000 key/value pairs. The largest value is 143MB in size, everything else smaller than 1MB. `mapred.child.java.opts` is set to `-Xmx500m`. I get an `Error: Java heap space` when processing this file. This is my Mapper:

```
public class MyMapper extends Mapper<Text, BytesWritable, Text, Text> {
    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        super.setup(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void map(Text key, BytesWritable value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        String content = new String(value.getBytes());
        // remove HTML tags (content is a HTML document)
        String content_no_html = Jsoup.parse(content).text();

        // try to find a regex match
        }
    }    
}
```

I thought it might be because my Map class is transforming the value from BytesWritable to String and then processing that string. But I tried to only process a key/value pair in the mapper if `value.getLength() < 8388608` (8 MB), still running out of memory.

I can increase the `-Xmx500m`, but I am afraid that this will not fix my issue, because I have a few thousand Sequence Files that I need to process and I don't know how big the biggest key/value pair is (I'm not interested in the big key/value pairs, thus the 8MB limit above). For the record, I tried this with a number of Sequence Files that resulted in ~2500 map steps, and the error occurred after the first 1990 or so were successful, which makes me think that a single key/value pairs size is the issue here.

Is there a way to only pass key/value pairs to the Mapper up to a size limit? Why do I even get `Error: Java heap space` in the first place?

### Edit

I tried to create a custom SequenceFileInputFormat as suggested, and found out that the Heap space error occurs before the map function is called. To be precise, the SequenceFileRecordReaders `nextKeyValue()` is what causes the error. I double checked this with running a map function that did nothing, and it still crashed. I couldn't find a way to fix the error there, so I guess increasing the memory is my only chance here.

Comment: what version of hadoop are you using?

Comment: I have not much thought to what could be the root cause of this specific case, but you can always provide your own InputFormat implementation that would discard record larger than a threshold.

Comment: are you getting the error for a local job runner or in a cluster? I assume cluster, then OOM error could be in your driver class - not at in a child process - try to debug it using local mode.

Comment: It's a cluster, and the Hadoop version is 2.0.0 (cdh).

Answer (score 1):

8 MB of HTML is still too big !

As an example, let's consider that your 8 MB of html text is an ul list with 80-bytes-long elements, you would have 1,000,000 elements:

```
<ul>
    <li class="item" data-index="000000">This is the <b>first</b> line.</li>
    <li class="item" data-index="000001">This is the <b>second</b> line.</li>
    [...]
    <li class="item" data-index="999999">This is the <b>last</b> line.</li>
</ul>
```

The Jsoup `Element` class (which is a subclass of `Node`) for each **li** element has the following structure, from which we can estimate (theoretically and approximately) the memory footprint for my example's html list:

- **Element.tag**: Refence to Tag object (in which 1 String + 8 boolean) => 64 bytes
- **Element.classNames**: Set of Class names => 56 bytes
- **Node.parentNode**: Reference to Node => 8 bytes
- **Node.attributes**: Reference to an Attributes object => 152 bytes

  - Contains a `LinkedHashMap<String, Attribute>` with 1 entry (48 bytes)

    - Attribute contains 2 Strings (~56*2=112 bytes)
- **Node.childNodes**: List of Nodes

  - 3 TextNodes (because of the **b** tag) => approx. 100 bytes each (text contents + Node fields again, this is memory inception !)

So the memory used by a single element of the list is around 580 bytes.

The total memory used by the 1,000,000 elements is about 580 MB.

Also, the main **ul** element contains a list of 1,000,000 references to those **li** elements in its childrenNodes field, so it takes 8 MB of memory.

Finally, when calling the `text()` if the text left after removing tags corresponds to 5MB of serialized characters, then you need a `String` of 5 million `char`s, taking 5,000,000*2 = 10 MB.

So if your html was like the list I showed, then you need to store in your heap, during that single call to the `map()` function:

- `new String(value.getBytes())` => ~ 16 MB
- `Jsoup.parse(content)` => ~ 590 MB
- `.text()` => ~ 10 MB
- **TOTAL => 606 MB**

No wonder you get a java heap space error with a heap of only 500 MB !

The "memory explosion" happens when parsing the file with JSoup, because it has to create lots of objects, and java objects, especially Strings, are heavy.

It all depends on what your html looks like. If your html has approximately the same concentration of html tags/attributes as the example I have, I think you can define your threshold to around 2 MB to be safe.

You can exit the map function at the beginning if `value.getLength() < 2_000_000` as you did. Or if it is important for you not to waste data, you could do something fancier, like run a regex to count the number of tags or attributes in the `content` string. If you have 20 MB of text but with only 1 tag inside, it will still fit into memory, no need to skip it.

Comment: I didn't know Jsoup would take that much memory, so thanks for that info! It's sadly not the cause of the error here, see my edit above.

Comment: Well don't worry, the jsoup OutOfMemory will still be waiting for you once you manage to get past reading the records ! But for now, how do you know there is a 143MB value in your Sequence File ? Is the seqfile compressed ? If it is compressed, that 143 MB might be >500MB uncompressed in memory...

Comment: The SequenceFile is compressed, but I know the source of it so I checked that; removing this file "fixed" the error. That's not feasible for all the data though, so I'm looking for a proper fix. I'll make sure that such big values won't be parsed to Jsoup.